# Change user's ID

Tags: development

I wonder if it is possible to programatically change user's id in Sharepoint 2010?
If it is, I would be very thankful for explantion on how to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you by ID mean the integer that follows the user, this cannot be changed.

The ID is part of the primary key, and exposed as a getable property in the object model:

[SPPrincipal.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spprincipal.id.aspx)
[SPUser.ID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spuser.id.aspx)

Why would you need this?

Comment: Because of mixed authentication... If the user is later created in AD and uses Win Authentication, I would like to map all his items etc. created by his old account to the new account. Thanks for answer.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you can change it on the backend database via SQL - **BUT THIS IS NOT SUPPORTED and ALL REFERENCES TO THIS USER MAY THEN BE BROKEN**.